# How do you replace a value by its percentile in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have a column of values and I want to replace each value by its percentile over the entire table. For example, if the column values are:

[1, 2, 6, 12, 18, 1, 2, 6, 12, 18]

I'd like to replace it by:

[20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]

Answer (score 1):

Use RANGE_BUCKET which returns the position in a sorted array.

For example, to replace each "duration" by its percentile:

```
WITH quantiles AS (
  SELECT 
    APPROX_QUANTILES(duration, 100) AS bins
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
)

SELECT
   start_station_name, 
   duration,
   RANGE_BUCKET(duration, bins)-1 AS duration_bucket
FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`, quantiles
LIMIT 10
```

For the specific example in the question:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT [1, 2, 6, 12, 18, 1, 2, 6, 12, 18] AS num
),

quantiles AS (
   SELECT  APPROX_QUANTILES(d,100) AS bins
   FROM data, UNNEST(num) AS d
)

SELECT 
   d, 
   RANGE_BUCKET(d, bins)-1
FROM data, UNNEST(num) AS d, quantiles
```